# How to init VersionControlServer class?

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs, repository

I want to download file from TFS 2013. I found the `VersionControlServer` class: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx)

But how to initialize it?

```
 VersionControlServer vs;
 vs.DownloadFile(repositoryPath,localPath); // vs not initialized!
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
String repositoryPath = "$/MyColl1/Folder1/Folder2/TargetFile.txt";
    String localPathStored = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "TargetFile.txt";
    String uriSite = "http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/../../vN.0/....asmx";
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(uriSite));

    VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    versionControlServer.DownloadFile(repositoryPath, localPathStored);
```