# Get list of unique files for specefic changesets

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, tfvc

Is there any way to get list of unique files for specefic changesets? using any front end techonology like jquery.
For Example - I want to retrive all list of files with path for changesets no 2223, 2224, 2250 like -

```
tfs\prod\072418\yellow.aspx
tfs\prod\072418\bg.jpeg
tfs\prod\072418\sent.xml
tfs\prod\072418\home.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole workspace at a specific changeset easily. You'd map a new workspace and then get the sources at a specific version.

It looks like you may be looking for "just the changed files", basically the contents of the changeset itself. That's actually harder. It may also be the wrong thing to seek. Let's first investigate that a bit, shall we?

When you open the Changeset details for any TFVC changeset you'll see a list of files that were associated with that changeset. For your purpose any `edit` and `add` operation would be the changed files. But any `delete` or `merge` or other item would result in either a file with unchanged contents or a file that no longer exists.

If you're only interested in listing the changes (and not the contents of the files), then from the commandline you can use:

```
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\Source\Workspaces\>tf changeset 29 /noprompt
Changeset: 29
User: Jesse Houwing
Date: Thursday, 14 September 2017 20:02:54

Comment:

Items:
  delete, source rename $/vsts-tfvc-tasks-test/changes.122204;X2
  rename                $/vsts-tfvc-tasks-test/changes.122204,old
```

It will list all the items and the type of action that was performed on them.
 You can save the individual files using `tf vc view`:

```
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\Source\Workspaces\>tf vc view /output:changes.122204,old changes.122204,old /version:c29
```

There is no built-in command which will just grab the files for an individual changeset. It can be accomplished relatively easily with [the `VersionControlServer` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796633/736079) and powershell should you want to do it. Or by invoking the above mentioned `tf vc` commands and parsing their output.

---

To do this through the API you have two options:

### REST

If you're talking to a recent TFS server/VSTS, you can use the [REST API to query TFVC changesets to get to their details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes?view=vsts-rest-4.1). This is the preferred a method going forward. Either directly using a WebClient (.NET) or Invoke-RestMethod (Powershell) or any other webclient. The [guidance to get started with the REST API is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

### SOAP Client

If you're talking to an older TFS server or need to support both old and new servers, then you can use the [Client Object Model to get access to the Changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb143081(v%3Dvs.120)).

```
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(registeredProjectCollection);
var versionControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

Comment: I would like to get it through API.

Comment: Added REST and SOAP details.